# Can my Google Analytics data be recovered? When I sign in, Google doesn't have it and is asking me to sign up for GA

Tags: google-analytics

I use google analytics. That is working without any problem. But today, when I log in to my account, google-analytics ask me to SIGN UP! 
All my site information is missing, Without Google giving me a warning.
What is the solution to recover them?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: That usually means that you signed into a different Google account than the one that has your analytics data.   I've never heard of Google just deleting all of a sites stats.   If Google actually has done so for you, you would be the first I've ever heard of.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen as a glitch for new users i've signed up to have access to my Google Analytics, though not for existing users.  If you are using your usual log-in I suspect it is an associated glitch and the log-in will work again shortly.